# How to get Azure Data Factory Tumbling Window Trigger to work with Daylight Savings Time

Tags: triggers, azure-data-factory, dst

I have some tumbling window triggers that are set to run at specific intervals 6 hours apart. They need to run at a designated time (think 5am and 11am, and so on) I have them set up so that they are self-dependent and dependent on a connection check trigger.

The problem arises when daylight savings comes around. Tumbling window triggers only work in UTC and when the clock changes in our time zone, the times they are triggered change by an hour (forward or back depending on the time of year). This causes data to be late to its destination and I am forced to manually deploy new triggers around daylight savings time.

I am wondering if there is a better way to work around daylight savings time as Tumbling Window Triggers do not support any time zone other than UTC and deploying new triggers every time is not an effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your requirement, it is actually different between 6 hours apart and setting scheduled triggers for 2 designated times which are 6 hours apart.

If you want to schedule the job for every 6 hours, the timezone should have no impact since the trigger should always trigger every 6 hours. This is the correct use case for tumbling window trigger.

If you want to schedule for designated times, you should go for scheduled trigger, which supports for timezones. For catering daylight saving time, you can simply select the timezone you want, ADF will auto adjust according to daylight saving time as specified in the UI.

[image]